# python re: no such group

Tags: python, regex

I'm newbie in Python. I can't understand why this code does not work:

```
reOptions = re.search(
    "[\s+@twitter\s+(?P<login>\w+):(?P<password>.*?)\s+]",
    document_text)
if reOptions:
    login = reOptions.group('login')
    password = reOptions.group('password')
```

I'm having an error:

```
IndexError: no such group
```

With document_text

```
Blah-blah
[ @twitter va1en0k:somepass ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[` and `]` are special regular expression characters. Escape them to match literal `[` and `]`.
See [Regular Expression Syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Comment: oh, thank you. but why does statements after if execute? how to know if re finded anything?

Comment: It's' not a matter of the statements being invalid, just that your expression attempts to match things that you didn't mean to - essentially, you're trying to match any of the characters within the [], not the special regular expression constructs you made. You can tell you matched something because reOptions is not None. You can use MatchObject.group with no arguments to see the entire string that was matched.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the brackets [ and ] as `\[` and `\]`.

```
\[\s+@twitter\s+(?P<login>\w+):(?P<password>.*?)\s+\]
```

Comment: oh, thank you. but why does statements after if execute? how to know if re finded anything?

Comment: Well, it's still a regular expression.  It just matches any of the literal characters between [ and ].  But the login and password groups don't exist, so you get the error.